# Inner Join returns different data sets

Tags: sql

When I write below query, it returns all time different sets.

```
SELECT title, content FROM Stack 
INNER JOIN Overflow ON Stack.OverflowId = Overflow.Id
```

For example;

desired result:

```
title    content
_____    _______
 a     -    c1
 b     -    c2
 c     -    c3
 d     -    c4
 e     -    c5
 f     -    c6
 g     -    c7
```

First run:

```
title    content
_____    _______
 g     -    c7
 d     -    c4
 c     -    c3
 b     -    c2
 f     -    c6
 e     -    c5
 a     -    c1
```

Second run:

```
title    content 
_____    _______
 d     -    c4
 a     -    c1
 f     -    c6
 b     -    c2
 g     -    c7
 e     -    c5
 c     -    c3
```

This is reality interesting for me.. 
Do you know the reason?

When I use below query it is OK.

```
SELECT title, content FROM Stack 
INNER JOIN Overflow ON Stack.OverflowId = Overflow.Id 
ORDER BY Stack.Id
```

But the question is

> Why do I need `ORDER BY` to get desired result?

Comment: Because if you don't specify an order the DB will return the results in an unpredictable order. Why should the DB waist performance on a guessed order every time you didn't specify one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect predictable order without ORDER BY. Without it you do not have control over in which order rows are returned. Reason lies in how SQL language is specified.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no inherent order in results. If order matters, specify the order you want using the `ORDER BY` clause. If it doesn't, then don't.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specifically state the ordering, the server will return the data in the way it will retrieve most quickly. This changed slightly in the upgrade from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005 I believe.

There's an insteresting article here about the detailed ins and outs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/05/02/588731.aspx